# No entiendo por que cambia el valor de la cadena char, siendo que solo modifico el primer carácter

Tags: c++, string, sprintf

El objetivo es obtener en "newword" la palabra comprimida de word, como resultado "a2b1c4a3" pero se modifica el valor de "a" a una cadena gigante y eso se termino copiando por sprintf a "newword". Creo que debe ser la falta de algún que falta y se está pasando la dirección de a en vez de su contenido.

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{   
    
  char word[30]={};
  char newword[30]={};
  char a[1];
  int i,count;
  count = 0;
  strcpy(word,"aabcccccaaa");
  //strcpy(newword," ");
  printf("tiene largo %d\n",strlen(word));
  a[0]=word[0];
  for(i=0; i<strlen(word)+1;i++)
  {

      if(a[0]==word[i])
        count++;
      else{
        printf("before: value a: %s\n",a);
        sprintf(newword,"%s%s%d",newword,a,&count);
        printf("letra %s tiene largo %d\n",a,count);
        printf("newword: %s\n",newword);
        //a[1]='\0';
        a[0]=word[i];
        count=1;
        }
    
  }
  printf("newword: %s numero %d\n",newword,strlen(newword));
  if(strlen(word)>strlen(newword)-1)
    printf("%s",newword);
  else
    printf("%s",word);
}
```

Imprime esto, el valor "a" va cambiando y se pierde el resultado.

```
tiene largo 11
before: value a: a
letra aa7339448 tiene largo 2
newword: a7339448
before: value a: ba7339448
letra ba7339448ba73394487339448 tiene largo 1
newword: a7339448ba73394487339448
before: value a: ca7339448ba73394487339448
letra ca7339448ba73394487339448ca7339448ba733944873394487339448 tiene largo 5
newword: a7339448ba73394487339448ca7339448ba733944873394487339448
before: value a: 4a7339448ba73394487339448ca7339448ba733944873394487339448
letra 4a7339448ba73394487339448ca7339448ba7339448733944873394484a7339448ba73394487339448ca7339448ba7339448733944873394487339448 tiene largo 1
newword: a7339448ba73394487339448ca7339448ba7339448733944873394484a7339448ba73394487339448ca7339448ba7339448733944873394487339448

--------------------------------
Process exited after 2.626 seconds with return value 3221225477
Presione una tecla para continuar . . .
```

Comment: `a` tiene una longitud de **1 solo caracter**, luego no lo puedes mostrar con `"%s"`. Tienes que usar `"%c"`.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el objetivo de hacer un string de un caracter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema está en esta línea:

```cpp
sprintf(newword,"%s%s%d",newword,a,&count);
```

Al usar `&count` estas agregando a la string la dirección de la variable count, en vez de su contenido.

Te sugiero definir `a` como un tipo char y también utilizar `%lu` cuando utilizas `strlen()` para dar el formato correcto y evitar el warning.

Quedaría algo como así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>


using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    
  char word[30]={};
  char newword[30]="";
  char a;//Mas facil definirlo como un char
  int i,count;
  count = 0;
  strcpy(word,"aabcccccaaa");
  //strcpy(newword," ");
  printf("tiene largo %lu\n",strlen(word));//%lu, porque es el tipo que devuelve que devuelve strlen
  a =word[0];
  for(i=0; i<strlen(word)+1;i++)
  {

      if(a==word[i])
        count++;
      else{
        printf("before: value a: %c\n",a);
        sprintf(newword,"%s%c%d",newword,a,count);//&count = direccion de la variable count
        printf("letra %c tiene largo %d\n",a,count);
        printf("newword: %s\n",newword);
        //a[1]='\0';
        a=word[i];
        count=1;
        }
    
  }
  printf("newword: %s numero %lu\n",newword,strlen(newword));
  if(strlen(word)>strlen(newword)-1)
    printf("%s",newword);
  else
    printf("%s",word);
}
```

El motivo por el cuál te imprime mal el valor de la variable `a` es porqué a la hora de usar `printf()` deberías de:

1.Utilizar el formato `%c` para tu carácter `a[0]`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{   
    
  char word[30]={};
  char newword[30]={};
  char a[1];
  int i,count;
  count = 0;
  strcpy(word,"aabcccccaaa");
  //strcpy(newword," ");
  printf("tiene largo %lu\n",strlen(word));
  a[0]=word[0];
  
  for(i=0; i<strlen(word)+1;i++)
  {

      if(a[0]==word[i])
        count++;
      else{
        printf("before: value a: %c\n",a[0]);
        sprintf(newword,"%s%c%d",newword,a[0],count);
        printf("letra %c tiene largo %d\n",a[0],count);
        printf("newword: %s\n",newword);
        //a[1]='\0';
        a[0]=word[i];
        count=1;
        }
    
  }
  printf("newword: %s numero %lu\n",newword,strlen(newword));
  if(strlen(word)>strlen(newword)-1)
    printf("%s",newword);
  else
    printf("%s",word);
}
```

2.Utilizar el formato `%s` y agregar el carácter de final de línea `\0` a tu variable `a`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{   
    
  char word[30]={};
  char newword[30]={};
  
  int i,count;
  count = 0;
  strcpy(word,"aabcccccaaa");
  //strcpy(newword," ");
  printf("tiene largo %lu\n",strlen(word));
  char a[2] ={word[0],'\0'};//Necesitas 1 espacio para el caracter de final de línea
  
  for(i=0; i<strlen(word)+1;i++)
  {

      if(a[0]==word[i])
        count++;
      else{
        printf("before: value a: %s\n",a);
        sprintf(newword,"%s%s%d",newword,a,count);
        printf("letra %s tiene largo %d\n",a,count);
        printf("newword: %s\n",newword);
        //a[1]='\0';
        a[0]=word[i];
        count=1;
        }
    
  }
  printf("newword: %s numero %lu\n",newword,strlen(newword));
  if(strlen(word)>strlen(newword)-1)
    printf("%s",newword);
  else
    printf("%s",word);
}
```